# Database Access Objects batchInsert() yii2 run another function after each record is inserted

Tags: yii2, yii2-model

I am using `batchInsert()` function of `Yii2` Database Access Objects. I need to run another function like sending email from PHP code after each record is inserted.What is the workaround to achieve this? Or is it possible to get all `AUTO_INCREMENT` ids of rows inserted? 
The code is

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->batchInsert(Address::tableName(), 
['form_id','address'], $rows)->execute();
```

I am using `batchInsert()` documented in https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-command#batchInsert()-detail

Comment: could be you need  db trigger  ..

Comment: I need some php function to be run

Comment: It doesn't seem to be invoking any event triggers. Are you ok with not such elegant solution?

Comment: @GytisTenovimas what is the solution?

Comment: `ActiveRecord` does not have `batchInsert()` method. Can you share some code sample?

Comment: @rob006   Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->batchInsert(Address::tableName(), ['form_id','address'
    ], $rows)->execute();

Comment: i am with @rob006, there is no batchInsert() method. that must be part of your own code.

Comment: @R13e https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-command#batchInsert()-detail

Comment: @user7282 yeah, sry. i figured out myself after posting my comment.

Answer (score 1):

First, you're not using ActiveRecord. More about ActiveRecord you can find in the documentation: [API](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activerecord) and [guide](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record). `Yii::$app->db->createCommand()` is a [DAO](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-dao) which is much simpler than ActiveRecord and does not support events in the same way.

Second, there is no `batchInsert()` for ActiveRecord and there is a good reason for that - it is hard to detect IDs of inserted records when you're inserting them in batch (at least in a reliable and DB-independent way). More about this you can read at [GitHub](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/pull/2070).

However if you know IDs of records or some unique fields before insert (for example user in addition to the numeric ID, it also has a unique login and/or email), you may just fetch them after insert and run event manually:

```
$models = Address::findAll(['email' => $emailsArray]);
foreach ($models as $model) {
    $model->trigger('myEvent');
}
```

But unless you're inserting millions of records, you should probably stick to simple foreach and `$model->save()`, for the sake of simplicity and reliability.

There is also a [yii2-collection](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-collection) official extension. This is still more like a draft and POC, but it may be interesting in the future.